# Перевод из отрицательного числа в положительное по модулю

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь перевести из отрицательного числа в положительное по модулю таким способом:

```
__int64 y=-127863182361;
__int64 p=156;
if (y<0)
    do {
        y += p;
    } while (y<0);
```

Все работает, но очень медленно, как можно ускорить, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для перевода числа в положительное по модулю вам просто надо выполнить Евклидово деление числа на модуль и взять остаток. В С/С++ нет встроенного Евклидова деления. Поэтому его приходится эмулировать

```
q = y >= 0 ? y / p : (y - p + 1) / p; // Евклидово деление
y -= q * p;                           // Остаток
```

или сразу остаток

```
y = y % p;                            // Остаток "фортран" деления
y = y >= 0 ? y : y + p;               // Остаток Евклидова деления
```

Вот и все.

---

Существуют разнообразные "бит-хакерские" варианты реализации вычисления остатка, целью которых является избежание ветвления, типа

```
y = y % p;
y += p & (-(y < 0));
```

хотя большого смысла в них в большинстве случаев нет.

Comment: [Хм.](https://ideone.com/jBW7Mk)

Comment: @wololo: Да, возмутительнейшее безобразие. Должно быть `y -= q * p`.

Answer (score 2):

Например, так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T mod(T val, T m)
{
    T res = val % m;
    if (res < 0)
        res = res + m;
    return res;
}

int main() 
{
    const size_t SIZE = 9;
    int_fast64_t val[SIZE] = {255, 256, 257,   0, -257, -256, -255,  -1, -127863182361};
    int_fast64_t m[SIZE]   = {256, 256, 256, 256,  256,  256,  256, 256,  156};

    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
        cout << val[i] << " mod " << m[i] << " = " << mod(val[i], m[i]) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Вывод](https://ideone.com/MjTDU9):

```
255 mod 256 = 255
256 mod 256 = 0
257 mod 256 = 1
0 mod 256 = 0
-257 mod 256 = 255
-256 mod 256 = 0
-255 mod 256 = 1
-1 mod 256 = 255
-127863182361 mod 156 = 99
```

Answer (score 0):

Какой - то странный перевод должно быть так:

```
__int64 y=-127863182361;
if (y<0)
{
    y *= -1;
}
```

либо с помощью битовых операций поменять первый бит.

Comment: Мне не просто надо положительное число получить, а именно по модулю взять его функция mod. С положительными числами понятно, %, но с отрицательными она не работает.

Comment: @Александр вообще работает. ну пишите `y%p+p`

Comment: @Александр, [ЧЯДНТ?](http://cpp.sh/2aavgc)

Comment: Тупанул, спасибо большое)

Answer (score 0):

Не усложняйте себе жизнь. Пример 1: использование функции `fabs` (модуль числа):

```
 #include <iostream>

    int main(void) {
        int x = -67;
        x = std::fabs(x);
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Пример 2, ещё проще:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    int x = -67;
    x = x < 0 ? -x : x;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Иначе понял суть Вашего вопроса (перевод из отрицательного числа в положительное по модулю). Так как верный ответ уже предоставлен, плюсую его.